# Allowing html tags in a postback

Tags: asp.net, html

I've got a textbox where the user can enter text that includes html markup.

Of course, when the page does anything that involves a postback, it breaks (error 500) because the parser thinks the html code in the textbox is a hack attempt.

Now, I know there is a way to allow it, but I can't for the life of me remember.

Help?

I'm using Visual Studio 2008, VB.NET, in case it's relevant.

Enjoy
Random

Answer (score 6, accepted):

at top of page:

```
<%@ Page ValidateRequest='False' %>
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe setting "ValidateRequest=False" in your page directive should solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable request validation as :

```
<%Page Language="C#" validateRequest="false" %>
```

or encode HTML tags at client side before posting form to server.

Comment: Thanks.

The end solution is that we're going to use something like TinyMCE for it, but we need a quick solution for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this issue by disabling validaterequest