# Posting HTML within an ASP.NET form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-3.5

I am using Master Pages in an ASP.NET MVC app that lets you submit HTML data as part of a form. Even when I set

```
<%@ Page ValidateRequest="false" %>
```

Or set

```
<pages validateRequest="false">
...
</pages>
```

in my web.config file i still get the same error:

---

A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client...

Description: Request Validation has detected a potentially dangerous client input value, and processing of the request has been aborted. This value may indicate an attempt to compromise the security of your application, such as a cross-site scripting attack. You can disable request validation by setting validateRequest=false in the Page directive or in the configuration section. However, it is strongly recommended that your application explicitly check all inputs in this case.

---

I am using ASP.NET Master Pages within an MVC app.

Any thoughts? See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688832/allowing-html-tags-in-a-postback).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In asp.net MVC validation occurs at the controller level rather than page, applying attribute [ValidateInput(false)] to the controller action should help